# Cannot setState inside onSendProgress in Dio library

Tags: flutter, progress-bar, multipartform-data, dio

I am doing this, to upload a file

```
dio.post(
  url,
  data: data,            
  onSendProgress: (int sent, int total) {
    print(sent / total); // works
    setState(() {
      _sendProgress = sent / total; // does not work
    });
  }
);
```

The print statement prints the progress, but the _sendProgress state variable only updates when the file has upload (it updates to 1).

Do you know a work around about this, or why it happens?

Thank you

Comment: any updates bro?

Comment: @HabibMhamadi nope

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your `_sendProgress` variable is integer and because of that your divide result rounding to `0` until it becomes `1` can you share your codes other parts.

Comment: What happens when you put print in setstate?

Comment: inside setState print(_sendProgress) prints the correct value

Comment: I will test this and get back to you.